# AutoGenerating routeId's in camel

Tags: apache-camel

In apache-camel, is there a way to auto generate routeId's overriding the existing ones with route numbers(generated in RouteDefinitionHelper)?

Comment: You can write your own route id when you define route - it is strongly recommended to have one too. May I know the intention of changing default route id?

Comment: I want the convention to be in the format  route:<component>:<UrlEndpoint> . So that i can recognize them nicely, among all those routes in the context.I want code to be precise and less verbose, even without giving the routeId, I should generate one with the above mentioned format.

Comment: I'm not sure about customizing camel route names internally. I feel it's a better practice to name your route once you configure.

Answer (score 1):

There is to the best of my knowledge no autoGeneration policy on routeNaming you can use, but you could do something similar to this:

```
private String myURI;

from("jms:queue:" + myURI).routeId("JmsComponent:" + myURI)
    .to("....");
```

By using something like blueprint or spring to inject your variable to the java class you can change your URI and it will adjust the route name accordingly.  You could also use the full URI in your private variable then parse the endpointURI yourself and format it for the routeId.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify them directly for routes as well as processors in your routes.

```
from("direct:start").routeId("MyMainRoute")
    .to("direct:out").id("MyOutputProcessor");
```

These ids will be visible in your jConsole so you can see statistics on your routes and processors as well.

Comment: That's fine but i want my route to automatically generate its own RouteId of this particular format route:<Component>:<EndpointUrl> .

Comment: I am fairly certain there is no existing way to set an automatic generation policy.  For each one of your routes you could set both  the from url and route url at the same time.  If you making a copy of a single route many times then you could create a parent bean with that route and use a single variable for the from uri and the routeId.  Other than that I think your line of thought isn't bad at all and you might want to open this as a feature improvement request.

Answer (score 0):

For spring-camel You can use this code:

```
@Component
public class UriNodeIdFactory extends DefaultNodeIdFactory {
@Override
public String createId(NamedNode def) {
    String key = def instanceof NamedRoute nr ? nr.getEndpointUrl()
       : def instanceof EndpointRequiredDefinition ed ? ed.getEndpointUri()
       : def.getShortName();
    if (key.contains("{{") && def instanceof OptionalIdentifiedDefinition od && od.getCamelContext() != null) {
        key = od.getCamelContext().resolvePropertyPlaceholders(key);
    }
    return key.replace(":", "-").replace(".", "_") + getNodeCounter(key).incrementAndGet();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining your routes using the java RouteBuilder you could subclass RouteBuilder and Override the from (and any other route building methods method):

```
public abstract class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public RouteDefinition from(String uri) {
       return super.from(uri).id("route:"+uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or even better, as configureRoute gets called for all :

    @Override
    protected void configureRoute(RouteDefinition route) {
        super.configureRoute(route.id("route:"+route.getEndpointUrl()));
    }